# CSS selector involving pseudo class first-child and dropcap

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to format HTML similar to below. Basically a quote is **optional**, and I need to dropcap the first letter of the body paragraph.

```html
<article>
 <p class="quote"> <!-- quote is optional -->
   Genius begins great works; labor alone finishes them.-- Joseph Joubert
 </p>
 <p> <!-- "L" is a dropcap -->
  Life is like a box of chocolates.
 </p>
 <p>...</p>
 <p>...</p>
</article>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
article > p:first-child:first-letter
{
 float: left;
 font-family: Georgia, serif;
 font-size: 360%;
 line-height: 0.85em;
 margin-right: 0.05em;
}
p.quote {
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

It doesn't work currently when the quote is introduced. AFAIK I can't select the article's first child P which is not class "quote." I'll use jQuery if I can't figure this out, but for now I'm looking for a way to do it CSS only.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can control/change the HTML, consider using a `blockquote` containing a `p`, instead of `p class="quote"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're OK with using CSS3 selectors, try using these (grouped together):

```
/* Select the first child if it's not a .quote */
article > p:not(.quote):first-child:first-letter, 
/* Or, if the first child is a .quote, select the following one instead */
article > p.quote:first-child + p:first-letter
{
 float: left;
 font-family: Georgia, serif;
 font-size: 360%;
 line-height: 0.85em;
 margin-right: 0.05em;
}
```

[See the jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/kZ7u9)

Otherwise I think you'll have to play with some overrides to get the desired effect.

#### Some explanation

The [negation pseudo-class `:not()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) is always processed **independently** of all other types, IDs, classes and pseudo-classes in the compound selector. This is regardless of how you arrange it with your other selectors.

To put it another way: you can't use `:not()` to remove, or filter out, elements that match what's in the negation, from a selection matched by the rest of the simple selector. It also means that the set of the elements matched by the `:*-child()` and `:*-of-type()` pseudo-classes is not affected by `:not()`.

So the first selector above,

```
article > p:not(.quote):first-child:first-letter
```

works roughly like this:

1. Find every `p` element.

   - If not found, ignore.
2. If found, check whether this `p` is the `:first-child` **and** if it's `:not(.quote)`.

   - If it's not the first child, ignore.
   - If it has the `quote` class, ignore.
3. If it matches both pseudo-classes, check whether this `p` is a child of `article`.

   - If not, ignore.
4. If so, grab its `:first-letter`.
5. Apply rules.

The second selector, on the other hand, is relatively straightforward:

```
article > p.quote:first-child + p:first-letter
```

All it does is take the `p` that comes right after the first child of `article` if it's a `p.quote`, and apply rules to its `:first-letter`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `<q>` or `<blockquote>` for the quote? then you can use

```
p:first-of-type:first-letter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 p.dropCap:first-child:first-letter {
float: left;
color: #903;
font-size: 75px;
line-height: 60px;
padding-top: 4px;
padding-right: 8px;
padding-left: 3px;
font-family: Georgia;
}
```