# Alternating Row Colours in CSS3 With DOM changing

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm using the following css to alternate the background colour of li elements, but need the css to be maintained if the rows get the .hidden class assigned to them (.hidden class being display: none;).

```
ul li:not(.hidden):nth-child(odd) {
    background: #fff;
}

ul li:not(.hidden):nth-child(even) {
    background: #f4f4f4;
}
```

Any ideas on how to keep the alternating colours while adding / removing li elements to / from the ul? Please only give a CSS based solution if possible. I may have to do it in JS but would prefer not to!

Cheers

Comment: I think you'll have to go with JavaScript for this, unfortunately (since JavaScript is better suited for handling DOM manipulations). Really sorry for dashing any high hopes! :(

Comment: I presume there isn't just a js function I can call to "re-initialize" the css on the modified DOM?

Answer (score 4):

Due to the way the `:not()` pseudo-class works, you cannot use it to filter elements out of the DOM to obtain a subset of elements on which to apply styles. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217086/css-selector-involving-pseudo-class-first-child-and-dropcap/5217102#5217102) for the nitty gritty.

**EDIT:** Apparently my solution below isn't supposed to work either. I need to take a break from answering questions or something. So I guess the only other feasible route may be to do this with JavaScript. I'm keeping this post here instead of deleting as I don't want to take the comments down with it.

<s>To this end, if you can modify the HTML, you can instead use a class that is common to all your `li`s and target that instead, in conjunction with `:nth-of-type()`:</s>

```
ul li.shown:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background: #fff;
}

ul li.shown:nth-of-type(even) {
    background: #f4f4f4;
}
```

Comment: @BoltClock: I don't think that's why it's not working - `nth-child` always applies to the element in relation to its siblings, not the results of the previous selector match.  So a child whose location is odd in relation to its siblings is always odd, regardless of other selectors.

Comment: @Andy E: Yes, but for something like `li#one li#two.hidden li#three`, `li#three` is not considered even despite the negation. It's still odd because `li#two` still exists. As a result, with the styles, `#one` and `#three` will have contiguous backgrounds. (Sorry for all this moving :P)

Comment: @BoltClock: yes, that is pretty much what I was trying to say :-p Your answer hints that the root of the problem is the `:not()` pseudo-class, but even if that worked the way the OP wanted the problem wouldn't be solved.  The *real* problem is a fundamental lack of understanding of the `nth-child` selector.  (And don't worry about it, your comment works better as an answer with a potential solution anyway - +1).

Comment: That's interesting, thanks. I have tried this but with no luck. They all show correctly until I hide one element (and remove the 'shown' class).

Comment: @Joel: Oh, crud... completely overlooked that, sorry!

Comment: Sweet ok.. is it just attr selectors/pseudo classes that always get applied to the element regardless of other classes? If so, crap! :)

Comment: @Joel: Let me experiment on jsFiddle and see if I can come up with something... *I shouldn't be doing this when I'm sick at home :)*

Comment: @Andy E: I think I misunderstood *both* `:nth-child()` and `:nth-of-type()`. I have **a lot of fixing** to do today... thanks again for your comment :)

Comment: @BoltClock: In response to your flag, I think editing the answer so it's as correct as possible and the comments are preserved as you've done is the best way to go.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: Got it. (You meant "editing the answer"...)

Comment: @BoltClock: Right.  It's been a long week.  :)

Answer (score 0):

What if you changed your .hidden to the following

```
.hidden {height:0px; overflow:hidden}
```

I haven't tested this code at all, but the elements would still be in the DOM for manipulation yet shouldn't be visible to the user.