# Selecting the nth-element of class X

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I select the nth-element of a X class using only CSS 3 selectors? Specifically, i need to select each even table row in a table to apply a style, but sometimes i insert a table row that needs to be ignored because it isn't data.

I tried using

```
tr.X:nth-child(even)
.X::nth-child(even)
```

and i know that `:nth-of-type()` exists but neither of those seems to fulfill my requirements.

Is it possible to achieve this with pure CSS3 ? If not i don't really mind, but i'll be glad to hear your ideas.

### HTML table

```
<table class="txls">
    <thead class="centro">
        <tr class="bg-gris">
            <td class="txlsb" rowspan="2" width="14">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="txlsb" rowspan="2">Linea</td>
            <td class="txlsb" colspan="7">Kilometros</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bg-gris">
            <td class="txlsb" width="100">Atenci&oacute;n</td>
            <td class="txlsb" width="100">Derecho de via</td>
            <td class="txlsb" width="100">Administrativos</td>
            <td class="txlsb" width="100">Contencioso</td>
            <td class="txlsb" width="100">Expropiados</td>
            <td class="txlsb" width="100">Construccion</td>
            <td class="txlsb" width="100">Regularizados</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="X">
            <td class="txlsb"><img src="imgs/collapse-medium-green.png" /></td>
            <td class="txlsb">XXX-45820-YYY</td>
            <td class="txlsb">12.50</td>
            <td class="txlsb">60.12</td>
            <td class="txlsb">8.00</td>
            <td class="txlsb">10.00</td>
            <td class="txlsb">0.00</td>
            <td class="txlsb">0.00</td>
            <td class="txlsb">18.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td class="txlsb bg-cancel">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="txlsc" colspan="8">
                <table class="txls w100">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="bg-verde2">
                            <td class="txlsb" width="14"><img src="imgs/collapse-medium-green.png" /></td>
                            <td class="txlsb">Zona Foo</td>
                            <td class="txlsb" width="100">3.00</td>
                            <td class="txlsb" width="100">1.00</td>
                            <td class="txlsb" width="100">0.00</td>
                            <td class="txlsb" width="100">0.00</td>
                            <td class="txlsb" width="98">4.00</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="txlsb bg-cancel">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="txlsc" colspan="6">
                                <table class="txls w100">
                                    <thead class="centro">
                                        <tr class="bg-gris2">
                                            <td class="txlsb"  width="100">Tramite</td>
                                            <td class="txlsb">Num. Caso</td>
                                            <td class="txlsb">Expediente</td>
                                            <td class="txlsb">Predio</td>
                                            <td class="txlsb" width="55">T. Inicial</td>
                                            <td class="txlsb" width="55">T. Final</td>
                                            <td class="txlsb bg-cancel" width="96">&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr class="X">
                                            <td class="txlsb">Administrativo</td>
                                            <td class="txlsb">12</td>
                                            <td class="txlsb">YC-AGR-12390-2011</td>
                                            <td class="txlsb">la chuchita</td>
                                            <td class="txlsb">12.1</td>
                                            <td class="txlsb">25.0</td>
                                            <td class="txlsb">3.00</td>
                                        </td>
                                        <tr class="X">
                                            <td class="txlsb">Contencioso</td>
                                            <td class="txlsb">13</td>
                                            <td class="txlsb">YC-AGR-52323-2011</td>
                                            <td class="txlsb">el almendro</td>
                                            <td class="txlsb">50.0</td>
                                            <td class="txlsb">51.0</td>
                                            <td class="txlsb">1.00</td>
                                        </td>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </td>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="X">
            <td class="txlsb"><img src="imgs/expand-medium-green.png" /></td>
            <td class="txlsb">AAA-83010-BBB</td>
            <td class="txlsb">50.92</td>
            <td class="txlsb">92.45</td>
            <td class="txlsb">10.08</td>
            <td class="txlsb">0.00</td>
            <td class="txlsb">0.00</td>
            <td class="txlsb">0.00</td>
            <td class="txlsb">0.00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your table html would be a great addition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CSS4 specifications](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/) call for the `:nth-match()` pseudo-selectors, but at the present time there is not one available for use. All the current pseudo-selectors are in the context of *all* elements that it can look at in the current branch. The `nth-child(even)` is only being applied to the `tr` and not the `.X`.

Comment: I agree with animuson that you are out of luck. I tried some trickiness with the :not selector, but no dice. It seems the nots are filtered at the end of the list.

http://jsfiddle.net/TpTrF/

    `tr:not(.ignore):nth-of-type(even) {  }`

Comment: @mrtsherman: Yes, everything currently is. I fiddled with this for this a few days a bit ago trying to get the first element floated left to have a border-radius on the left, and the first element floated right to have border-radius on the right. Just have to do it manually for now.

Comment: @mrtsherman: [They are evaluated and filtered simultaneously.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217086/css-selector-involving-pseudo-class-first-child-and-dropcap/5217102#5217102)

Comment: I swear, I need to move that whole chunk about pseudo-class evaluation out into a new question and answer.