# Adding :last-child or :last-of-type to nav menu

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Normally CSS is my thing, but I'm somehow dumbfounded why this isn't working for me. I'm building a site through Cargo for CMS purposes and you can see it here: http://cargocollective.com/mikeballard

In my menu, I have five main categories, and clicking on them (images, for example) reveals the list of work under that category.

```
<div id="menu_2444167" class="link_link">
    <a id="p2444167" name="mikeballard" target="" href="http://cargocollective.com/mikeballard/filter/images">Images</a>
</div>
<div id="menu_2444188" class="project_link">
    <a name="mikeballard" rel="history" href="mikeballard/#2444188/Ultra-Nomadic-Def-Smith-Cycle-2011">Ultra Nomadic Def Smith Cycle, 2011</a>
</div>
<!-- more divs here -->
<div id="menu_2444201" class="project_link">
    <a name="mikeballard" rel="history" href="mikeballard/#2444201/Archive">Archive</a>
</div>
```

Basically, I'm trying to select the last div in this set, and add a margin-bottom:15px to that div. I've tried using:

`.project_link:last-child` or `.project_link:last-of-type` but it doesn't seem to be working.

The HTML, which can't be altered too much to rely on Cargo, isn't great as if they had used list items, instead of divs with anchor tags I'm assuming this would be a lot easier.

Comment: If the last `.project_link` is the last child of whatever the parent element is, `:last-child` should work. If it is also the last `div` element, `:last-of-type` should work. Do you happen to be testing in an old version of IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:last-of-type` and `:last-child` selectors are not supported before IE9.

---

Class names, etc are *not looked at* when it comes to the `:last-child` and `:last-of-type` selectors. The `.project_link:last-child` selector will *only* trigger if the specific element is *the last child* in the parent element and has the class "project_link", and the `.project_link:last-of-type` selector will *only* trigger if the specific element is *the last element of that type* and has the class "project_link".

Both should trigger in a supporting browser, since it is implied as `*.project_link:last-of-type` and will check for every type of element inside that parent (which appears to only be divisions anyways). The last division shown here has the class "project_link" which would match this rule. The only reason these wouldn't trigger is if you had extra elements (or divisions) below what you're showing us, or you're using a browser which doesn't support it.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that .project_link:last-of-type should work? Thanks for the explanation. If you look at the URL I gave you, you can see there are more divisions. I guess there's no way of selecting it.

Comment: @Richard: No, not at the time. But, I have recently posted information about [CSS4's upcoming `:nth-match()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480185/selecting-the-nth-element-of-a-x-class/8480220#8480220) selector.