# Selecting a class and first 3 of the rest; nth-child and nth-of-type useless

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a DOM element (#installations) with a number of children, only one of them has a class .selected. I need to select this class and the first 3 of the rest (:not(.selected)) and show them - the goal is to have only 4 elements shown, regardless of which element has the class .selected.

The problem is, in the expression:

```css
#installations > *:not(.selected):nth-of-type(-n+3), .selected
```

:nth-of-type() disregards the :not() selector and just selects the first 3 children of #installation. For example, if I have this HTML:

```html
<div id="installations">
    <div id="one"/>
    <div id="two"/>
    <div id="three" class="selected"/>
    <div id="four"/>
    <div id="five"/>
</div>
```

I will only have one, two, three selected and not the first four. The logical implication is that :nth-of-type() will have only (one, two, four, five) to select from, since :not() already excluded the selected one, thus selecting (one, two, four), and then the other part of the selector `, .selected` will add the selected element.

If .selected is not in the first four elements, let's say it's the sixth, we will have the first three + sixth elements selected.

**To clarify: selecting .selected plus 3 adjacent elements is also fine. However, I this is also difficult in case .selected is in the last 3 (if we select the next 3 adjacent elements)**

Comment: Pseudo-classes are not processed sequentially; they are all evaluated together on each and every one of your elements. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5217102/106224) for details (also covers `:not()`). In your case, `:not(.selected):nth-of-type(-n+3)` picks up the first two elements (the third being `.selected`), and `.selected` picks up the third.

Comment: That is the problem. If only I could exclude .selected in the first part of the selector (before the first pseudo-class). Alternatively, I can put a class ".unselected" on all the other elements, but I was hoping for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, pseudo-classes are not processed sequentially; they are all evaluated together on each and every one of your elements. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5217102/106224) for details.

After a bit of tinkering around, given your HTML and the conditions by which to select elements, I came up with the following, *long* list of selectors:

```css
/* The first three children will always be selected at minimum */
#installations > div:nth-child(-n+3),
/* Select .selected if it's not among the first three children */
#installations > div.selected,
/* If .selected is among the first three children, select the fourth */
#installations > div.selected:nth-child(-n+3) ~ div:nth-child(4)
```

For this to work, one simple assumption has to be made: the `selected` class will only appear on one element at a time.

You'll need to combine all three selectors in the same rule in order to match the four elements you're looking for. Notice the commas in my code.

[Interactive jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/pCUrf) (for testing the selector with the class in different child elements)

---

For what it's worth, it's easier if you can fall back to JavaScript. As an example, if you use jQuery, its [`:lt()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector) makes things a little simpler:

```js
// Apply styles using this selector instead: #installations > div.with-jquery
$('#installations')
    .children('div.selected, div:not(.selected):lt(3)')
    .addClass('with-jquery');
```

[Interactive jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/AHhWy) (ignore the JS code in this demo, it's only there to make it interactive)

Comment: @Ivo: No problem. Let's just say I needed a puzzle to crack my head on :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use are adjacent sibling selectors. Here's an example I cooked up that is working in Safari (not tested elsewhere). Only 'Two', 'Three', and 'Four' items are displayed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .the-list li {display:none;}
      .the-list li.selected {display:block;}
      .the-list li.selected + li {display:block;}
      .the-list li.selected + li + li {display:block;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ol class='the-list'>
      <li>One</li>
      <li class='selected'>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
      <li>Four</li>
      <li>Five</li>
      <li>Six</li>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Adjacent sibling selectors are supported by every browser, business requirements notwithstanding (read: except IE6).

Comment: Wait wait, the OP wants the first three + selected, unless selected is in the first three, in which case it skips it and selects the other three elements surrounding it?

Comment: And if the last element has the class ".selected", only it will be displayed. Doesn't work as well.

Comment: Yup -- looks like I didn't read the original question quite thoroughly enough. At some degree of complexity, CSS alone ceases to be a good tool for the job. I think using some JavaScript for this one will remove a lot of pain. Even if you come up with a CSS rule that will work, if the code for it is nearly impenetrable, what happens the next time you have to maintain it?

Comment: @Steve Jorgensen: You're right, using JS will save a lot of pain. See my updated answer. It just *happens* that a CSS solution exists here given the circumstances...