# Style using nth-child to keep table's aspect (alternating row colors) updated

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a CSS table like this:

(this is a reliable simplification of my system)

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="data">
        abc
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="data">
        def
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="data">
        ghi
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="data">
        jkl
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have a CSS like this:

```
div.table div.row:not(.hide):nth-child(2n){
    background-color: #D7D4DA;
}
div.table div.row:not(.hide):nth-child(2n+1){
    background-color: #E4E8EB;
}

.hide{
    display:none;
}
```

The purpose is:
When a line is hidden (using the class hide), the styling of the table should remain the same (each line with a different color between the two available). Instead, it get's broken.

According to firefox's firebug, the `:nth-child` is applied before the `:not`, not after (as I wanted). How can that be solved?

Note: Altering the HTML is a no go. This is something dynamically made using javascript.

My purpose is not to count for the nth-child the lines that are hidden in order to maintain the styling even if the line isn't visible

Comment: I've seen you posted this question the other day and I couldn't figure it out. You might want to use javascript/jquery for this.

Comment: You cannot change the evaluation order of pseudo-classes. Everything in a compound selector is evaluated "at the same time" on any given element. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5217102/106224) for an explanation. Also, I'm sorry that you have to put up with a script that outputs a CSS table that clearly should have been an HTML table.

Comment: @BoltClock♦ thx, man. Seems like I'll have to put up using classes to mark the nodes in the two colors and use js to change the classes when a line is hidden. Thx (again).

Comment: Can you add in the css to make that look like the table you want, so that we can spend time working on the problem rather than the basic layout. Cheers

Comment: There's no CSS solution. CSS is not prepared to deal with this specific situation. The only way around is using javascript. I use this with nth-child and then I override with js when there's hidden stuff

Comment: A possible way around is using a repeating image as a background of the table container.

Comment: If the size of a row changes puff.....

Comment: Do you have access to js as well?  You could add "even" and "odd" classes to all the elements and then reassign those classes with jquery excluding the .hide elements after the hide event happens.

Comment: @squarecandy I have js in the page, I just wanted ot have a reaction that does not depend on js. Anyway, it's solved now. I already have a solution that works. Does not work as I intended but it works. I just use the children[] and check 1 by 1 applying even or odd classes for the ones that do not have the substring "hide".

Comment: @BoltClock--I'd be interested in your thoughts about the solution I posted for this.

Answer (score 2):

### Pure CSS Answer (CSS3)

There are some careful considerations to take into account (see below), but [there does appear to be a way to do this in pure css](http://jsfiddle.net/yjkLT/140/) (note that fiddle uses the fake `div` table per this post, but it could be done with real html tables) using a `linear-gradient` with color stops (technique found [here](http://lea.verou.me/2010/12/checkered-stripes-other-background-patterns-with-css3-gradients/)) on the `table` background.  The key to make it flexible with `font-size` changes (or zooming) is to set the height portion of the `background-size` to twice the `line-height` set for the rows.

**Considerations:**

1. `line-height` and `font-size` for `row` should be explicitly set with `em` units (except see note #5 below).
2. If `padding` is set on the `table` (not recommended) then some type of adjustment to either `background-position` or `background-clip` will likely need to be done to accommodate the padding.
3. If top or bottom `padding` or `margin` is set on the `row` then it should be in `em` units and added to the `line-height` value before calculating the doubled `linear-gradient` height.
4. This technique will change color of background ***within a row*** if that row has multiple lines in it ([see **the last table** in my example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yjkLT/140/)).
5. If some other fixed height element were in the rows (images set to 20px high), then the `row` height and `linear-gradient` height could be set based off pixel values.

I have not taken the time to play around with #2 and #3 above to figure out for sure the exact adjustments needed, but theoretically it should be possible to accommodate those things if necessary.

Comment: A fiddle with 140 revisions. You've been busy!

Comment: @BoltClock--yes, too much time on it for sure. I thought I had an `nth-child` solution until I tested it with mixed types of hides in http://jsfiddle.net/yjkLT/67/ (note all the tables were good until the last two).

Comment: Yeah, you won't get very far with `:nth-child()` once you start mixing them up, because it's just not designed to handle that kind of dynamism (although with `:nth-match()` in CSS4 it may be as easy as `.row:nth-match(2n of :not(.hide))` and `.row:nth-match(2n+1 of :not(.hide))`). Meanwhile with CSS3, it turns out that linear gradients with hard color stops *are* great for striped patterns as long as legacy support isn't paramount, so you have my vote :)

Comment: @BoltClock--Nice (the CSS4 info and the upvote). I tried using `.hide:nth-of-type` to get the count on the `.hide` elements, only to find out that it does not work that way (though in my mind, it should), and instead looked to type as `div`. If I could have figured out how to count the `.hide` elements only (with css and selecting off that) I think I could have made a working solution based off `nth-child`.

Comment: [`:nth-of-type()` doesn't look at classes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/106224), it only looks at types (`div`, `td`, etc), so that one's out too. One of the reasons why they proposed `:nth-match()`.

Comment: Nice try but there's the problem no 4. Except for that1 everything is great and great job *thumbsup*

Comment: @brunoais--Yes, I have not figured out if there is a way for me to counteract the #4 consideration. For some tables, that would not be an issue (which is why I posted the answer), but for other tables it would definitely be cause to not use this solution.