# Resetting zebra style after removing rows from table

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table that, with bootstrap, uses `:nth-child` to style alternating table rows. However, whenever I remove a row with jQuery `.hide()` the alternating rows break.

HTML:

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table id='t1' class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover table-even-widths">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Heading A</th>
            <th>Heading B</th>
            <th>Heading C</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id='r1'>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='r2'>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='r3'>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='r4'>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='r5'>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

`$('#r4').hide();`

http://jsfiddle.net/saznq/1/

I was wondering if there was an easy way to sort of reset the table with the new configuration. I can always make my own `.even` and `.odd` class and filter through the table after every update to remove and reapply the classes, but was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: I don't wish to remove it from the DOM as it's togglable. It's easiest to use `.hide()` and `.show()` rather than adding it to a queue of removed elements, where it was in the table, and yada yada.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting every second visible table row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656915/selecting-every-second-visible-table-row)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from `$('#r4').remove();`, you could use something like this:

```
$('#r4').after('<tr></tr>').hide();
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/Sku22/)

This hides the element, and adds an empty `<tr>` element after it, displacing its removal and thereby doesn't disturb the `:nth-child` styling.

Comment: This... might work well. I hate adding 'filler' elements like this, but it seems like it would work. I'll have to play with it a bit and see if it'll work with my implementation. =)

Comment: @Ryan Yea - it works well. I used something like this recently. The problem is that `:nth-child` doesn't know to skip over the hidden elements. This essentially displaces it.

Comment: After fiddling a little i came up with other solution `$('#r4').hide().appendTo('table thead');`

Answer (score 2):

This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656915/selecting-every-second-visible-table-row) by [Manuel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/319422/manuel).

This is Manuel's code, using JQuery:

```
$('tr').removeClass('alternate')​
$('tr:not(.hide):odd').addClass('alternate')​
```

And here is the original [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LpXrF/).

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? I have given credit to the original poster and flagged the question as a duplicate.

Comment: A bit old, but this code works well for me. You had just a typo: $('tr').removeClas('alternate')​

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this article by Christian Heilmann (December 2013)](http://christianheilmann.com/2013/12/12/zebra-tables-using-nth-child-and-hidden-rows/)

Some of the solutions posted there are:

### 1) Repeating gradient background (CSS only)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/codepo8/LJ5LU/2/light/)**

### 2) Mixture of `nth-of-type`, `nth-child` and the tilde selector. (CSS only)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/codepo8/LJ5LU/3/light/)**

### 3) Storing  in a cache object

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/codepo8/LJ5LU/4/light/)**

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT

After reading your comment, i added an example on how to extract the desired row.

---

[$.hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) only hides visually an element. You have to remove the element from the DOM, or alternativelly extract it from the table, to get the expected results.

### To remove the element, you can use [$.remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

`$('#r4').remove()`

### To extract the element, you can use [jQuery.appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

To extract the row without removing it from the DOM, it must be appended to an element outside the table `tbody`. This can be done in different ways, but to avoid extra markup you can simply append the element, once hidden, to the table `thead`.

`$('#r4').hide().appendTo('table thead');`