# Is it possible to chain :not() then :last-child?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to style (CSS only) the last child element while excluding those with a specific class.

For example, I want to style

```
<ul>
  <li>Bar</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
  <li>Should have a green background</li>
  <li class='foo'>Bar</li>
</ul>
```

The last li without class 'foo' should be green. I tried

```
li:not(.foo):last-child {
    background-color: green;
}​
```

or

```
li:not(.foo):last-of-type {
    background-color: green;
}​
```

but it doesn't works.

See http://jsfiddle.net/gentooboontoo/V7rab/2/

Comment: using last-child itself will give rise to cross browser issues.. ur best off using `id` on that `li` element you want..

Comment: It's so strange why people take issues with one CSS3 selector and forget about the rest. If a browser doesn't support one CSS3 pseudo-class (`:last-child`), it's very unlikely to support any of the rest (`:not()` and `:last-of-type`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that will work (it doesn't work, but I don't think it *should* work anyway)

The selector is working, but the second-to-last `li` is never going to be the `:last-child` because it isn't the last-child...

It isn't like jQuery's `not()` method which actually removes the specified element from the selection. The CSS `:not` selector/filter will ignore the element, but not remove it from the page

Comment: Good, concise answer. Here's another explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5217102/106224

Answer (score 8):

The answer to your question *Is it possible to chain `:not()` then `:last-child?`* (or, more simply, *can pseudo-classes be chained?*) is very much a yes. But as others have pointed out, if an `li:last-child` has an `id="foo"` then nothing will be selected. As a demonstration, a similar expression

```
li:not(.bar):last-child {
    background-color: green;
}​
```

works just fine. The problem is that successive selectors all apply to the entire context, not to a subset specified by previous expressions so `li:not(.foo):last-child` is identical to `li:last-child:not(.foo)`, which is clearly not what is required.

Comment: I tried also

    li:not(.foo):last-of-type {
        background-color: green;
    }​

But it still didn't work, which is coherent with your answer.

Comment: `:last-of-type` doesn't look at an element's class.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one last child inside any element. In your example, it's `<li class='foo'>Bar</li>`. If you have exact number of children though, you could use adjacent-sibling combinator:

```
LI:first-child + LI  + LI + LI  {/* here are declarations for 4th LI. */}
```

Comment: That would select all `li` elements that have at least three immediately preceding `li` siblings; i.e. the fourth onwards. You would use `:nth-child(4)` or `:nth-last-child(2)` to do what you describe.

Comment: Thanks, I've added `:first:child` to first of `LI` selectors now. `:nth-child()` is not as cross-browser as adjacent-sibling combinator is (IE7+).

Comment: that's better, but the point reamins: that there is no way in CSS to select the last of a set of siblings that doesn't belong to a given class. Indeed, there is no way to filter the results of previous selector.

Answer (score 0):

Applying 'last-child' will give browser issue. so I tried in Jquery.

If you need use this code.

```
var a = 0
$('ul li').each(function() {
   $(this).attr("id",a);
    a++; 
});
var b = a-1;
$('#'+b).attr('style','background-color:green');​
```