# CSS :not([class*="hidden"]):nth-of-type(4n+1) not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

Please run the snippet to see what my problem is. I have a series of divs floating left. After a defined number of divs, I want them to break to a new line, in my example every 5th div should clear the float so it starts in a new line. So far no problem, which comes when I have some divs with a certain class, here `class="hidden"` which I do not want to count in my rule, which is why I exclude it here:

```
.box:not([class*="hidden"]):nth-of-type(4n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

As you can see in the example snippet, the third (hidden) div is still being counted towards the nth-of-type-rule which leads to an unwanted "line-break" after div no. 4.

Anyone any idea what I am doing wrong in my selector?

[Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/connexo/8nazb63y/)

```css
.box {
  background-color: #a00;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  height: 64px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 64px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.box:not([class*="hidden"]):nth-of-type(4n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box hidden">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>
<div class="box">5</div>
<div class="box">6</div>
<div class="box">7</div>
<div class="box">8</div>
<div class="box">9</div>
<div class="box">10</div>
<div class="box">11</div>
<div class="box">12</div>
<div class="box">13</div>
```

Comment: CSS selectors doesn't work the way you think, that selector doesn't exclude the box with class hidden of the count on nth-of-type....just don't apply the clear if the 4n+1 has the class hidden

Comment: `.box:not([class*="hidden"]):nth-of-type(4n+1)` here `:not` doesn't work as you might expect. Check with dev-tools to what `.box` css is applied

Comment: I've added a fiddle. How would you solve the problem with pure CSS?

Comment: Not possible with just CSS OP

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but the negation really ought to say `:not(.hidden)` rather than `:not([class*="hidden"])`.

Comment: Why? `:not([attribute*="value"])` should exclude elements which have `value` occurring in their `attribute`. Since class is a regular attribute, `.box` should work similar to [class*="box"], shouldn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 :nth-child() with a class selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/css3-nth-child-with-a-class-selector)

Comment: @connexo: The `*=` will match things like `class="box hidden-bla-bla"` where the other class is "hidden-bla-bla", not "hidden". Granted if you had total control over the markup this would not be an issue, but it's still not entirely accurate. A more accurate counterpart would be `[class~="hidden"]` with a `~=` instead of `*=`, which takes into account the whitespace and is basically equivalent when dealing with HTML. But you might as well just use a class selector at that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.box` and `:not()` portions of your selector are irrelevant to `:nth-of-type()`. The only thing that is considered by `:nth-of-type()` is the fact that these elements are all `div`s. You could specify `div:nth-of-type(4n+1)` and it would match the same elements in exactly the same order (albeit without the attribute negation), even if there happen to be any other `div` elements in the same parent that are not `.box`.

My answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/css3-nth-childodd-with-a-selector) explains in detail why these selectors don't work the way you would expect, but the gist is that every selector operates independently, and `:nth-of-type()` just happens to care only about the element type. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217086/css-selector-involving-pseudo-class-first-child-and-dropcap/5217102#5217102) for an illustrated example.

Due to the way current CSS selectors work, there isn't a way to filter out those elements using pure CSS; you will need to use JavaScript to count elements.

Comment: Well, tbh that's disappointing, to say the least. Is there a reason why this makes sense? Or is that just for simplyfying the implementation for the browser companies? Issues like the one I've described should be quite common, and it shows a real deficite in CSS 3 if you have to use JS to solve this.

Comment: @connexo: Selectors 4 proposes a solution to this in the form of `.box:nth-child(4n+1 of :not(.hidden))` but I don't know if it was only added when drafting Selectors 4, or if it was proposed for Selectors 3 but deferred because of implementation difficulties.

Comment: Maybe I should try using flex boxes. Still I'd need to create a fallback solution for older browsers. And even if I did there would still be no solutions for older browsers that have no JS available, right?

Comment: Probably not, and that's unfortunately where you will have to make compromises.

Comment: 20 years of CSS development and there is still no working solution for something as simple as that... :(